# Should I install Microsoft Redistributables not marked as "Supported"?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, drivers, odbc

I have a requirement to upgrade one of our Operating Systems from Windows Server 2012R2 to Windows Server 2016. The hosted application requires numerous ODBC Drivers that in turn require a bunch of Microsoft Redistributables. My problem is that several of the redistributable packages are not listed as supported for Windows Server 2016.

For example

- [Microsoft Access Runtime 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=50040)
- [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)

We also need to install Cloudera Impala ODBC driver which according to the [documentation](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/other/connectors/impala-odbc/2-6-9/Cloudera-ODBC-Driver-for-Impala-Install-Guide.pdf) is compatible with Windows Server 2016, however the documentation also tells us the driver needs [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=40784) which according to Microsoft is not supported on Windows Server 2016.

We also require [SQL Server ODBC Driver 17](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567) and this is listed as Windows Server 2016 supported, so it looks like Microsoft's documentation is updated.

What's the risk of proceeding with installing these redistributable packages on an apparently unsupported OS? Should this be avoided completely? Or would it be reasonable to test and risk accept if successful?

Comment: `C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 which according to Microsoft is not supported on Windows Server 2016.`. That is not accurate. VC++ redistributables are supported on all Windows platforms that are not EOL. You seem to be reading old documentation that was created before Windows Server 2016, and assuming it isn't supported. Microsoft isn't going to go back to every web page and update it with newer OS's when they are released. Access runtimes are supported by the application vendor, that is who you should check with.

Comment: Given the web pages I'm looking at are the official download pages for the software, I'd have thought it would make sense to keep those maintained at least as to avoid any confusion. On the whole though I agree with you, since Cloudera say their driver is supported on 2016 with that VC++ distributable it does indicate the pages aren't maintained. With regards to Access, I also found [this](https://products.office.com/en-gb/office-resources?rtc=1#coreui-heading-38bzjvj) under 'Office standalone applications' which mentions the full product Access 2016 is compatible, so the runtime should be too

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2661358/minimum-service-pack-levels-for-microsoft-vc-redistributable-packages has the supported operating systems and service packs levels for each Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package.